# Create variable of weights from array

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensor

I have an array : [1, 4, -10, 3, 5]. I'm trying to create a `Variable` of weights using that array.

After doing training, I print the weight as:

```
result = sess.run(w)
print(result)
```

the `result` is just the array in the format [1, 4, -10, 3, 5].

How I tried to create a `Variable` from the array:

```
 c = [1, 4, -10, 3, 5]
 for i in range(len(c)): 
     w = tf.Variable(c[i], name='weights')
```

Obviously, this weight result is wrong, and I've spent hours looking at documentation and SO posts. How do I create a `Variable` using that array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to loop through the elements; Rather simply use the whole list at once as in:

```
In [21]: vals = [1, 4, -10, 3, 5]

# create Variable `W`
In [22]: W = tf.Variable(initial_value=vals, name='weights')

# initialize all variables
In [23]: init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

In [24]: with tf.Session() as sess:
    ...:     sess.run(init)
    ...:     print(W.eval())


# prints
[  1   4 -10   3   5]
```